# [Vue warn]: Property or method "$v" is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I wanted to make a validation on the match of passwords with the following error:

> *vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "$v" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure
> that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for
> class-based components, by initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.*

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';
import VueTheMask from 'vue-the-mask';

Vue.use(Vuelidate, VueTheMask);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**My form**

```
...

<form action="#" method="GET" @submit.prevent="pswResetHendler">
    <label class="input__label" for="psw">Yangi parolni kiriting</label>
    <input
        class="input input__psw"
        type="password"
        name="psw"
        required
        v-model="password"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.password.$error }"
    />
    <label class="input__label" for="psw">Yangi parolni qayta kiriting</label>
    <input
        class="input input__psw"
        type="password"
        name="psw"
        v-model="confirmPassword"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.confirmPassword.$error }"
    />
    <span
        class="input__error match-error"
        v-if="!$v.confirmPassword.sameAsPassword"
        >Kiritilgan parollar bir xil bo’lishi lozim, Qayta urinib ko’ring!</span
    >
    <button class="login-btn" type="submit">KIRISH</button>
</form>
 ...

<script>
import { sameAs } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
export default {
    name: "password-reset",
    data() {
        return {
            password: "",
            confirmPassword: "",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        pswResetHendler() {
            this.$v.$touch();
            if (this.$v.$invalid) {
                return;
            }
            this.$router.push("/");
        },
    },
    validation: {
        confirmPassword: { sameAsPassword: sameAs("password") },
    },
};
</script>
```

Please help me guys I can't solve this for a day ((((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm really sorry guys )
I wrote the property `validations` incorrectly. I wrote

```
 validation: {
        confirmPassword: { sameAsPassword: sameAs("password") },
 },
```

instead of this I had to write

```
 validations: {
        confirmPassword: { sameAsPassword: sameAs("password") },
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line

```
Vue.use(Vuelidate, VueTheMask);
```

by

```
Vue.use(Vuelidate);
Vue.use(VueTheMask);
```

For more information check this [article](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-form-validation-with-vuelidate/)

Comment: Okay have this change applied anyway!!! are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Please check the last few blocks of the article, where they would have implemented the same using mixins

Comment: i changed but I get the same (

Comment: Ok bro I'll try with mixins

Comment: if that worked, please dont forget to upvote dude :)

Comment: of cource bro ) I will definitely do

Answer (score 0):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate);
```

Import in main.js or at component level